# GAE Servlet invoking Tibco BusinessWorks http receiver

Tags: java, google-app-engine, tibco

I would like to ask if it is possible for a servlet hosted on google app engine to invoke and start a tibco businessworks process through the http receiver palette option.

I am quite lost in determining how to set up the http connection (What port and host to listen to.etc)

Would appreciate any help in pointing me in some direction.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If  the process is Not running how can you invoke it ? Anyway you cannot start  it via http

Here a simple tutorial about the http palette 
http://teknoscope.com/data/tibco/tibco-http-messaging-palette-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You might have to develop **a webservice(using service palette) in Businessworks and deploy it in a server accessible through internet ( by outside world)**. Also you can expose your WSDL using the inbuilt resource provider available in the business works engine.

Once the service is exposed to the outside world, you can always consume the services like any other service from Appengine servlet.

I believe the above solution should work.